# Simulate a network share in order to share files

Tags: c#, networking, window, file-sharing

Often times a program requires a **file that happens to be on a network location**. Take for instance Outlook.  If I where to place an outlooks database (.pst file) in a network location then windows will make that "transparent" to the user and outlook will still be able to work. Another example could be quickbooks and many more. (as long as you have permissions to write and read)

For this example let's use Microsoft Word. If I would want to open a file in some other computer in the network I would be able to navigate to it as:

[image]

and open the file that I want because we are on the same network.

**Now my question is** how will I be able to simulate that? I want to have a virtual directory on the internet where I can place lets say my .pst file and then select it from windows explorer as:

[image]

(this example obviously does not work)

Will it be possible to do that? I believe windows uses a tcp connection with the host computer and then the host responds with he files that it shares. I will like to implement a program that does that so that I could avoid having to create a vpn. Also it will be nice if I could have my pst (outlook database file) on the internet so that all my computers open the same outlook database.

**Note my purpose of this question is to open an outlook database file on a network location. I will like to be able to select a file on the internet from `windows open file dialog`. Also in todays world everything pretty much exists. I will like to create it lol**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows provides a network redirector for CIFS (Common Internet File System, formerly SMB Server Message Block) resources.  Writing a CIFS server is the easiest approach.

But you can also use one of the other existing redirectors, such as NFS, WebDAV, or Netware.  And it's also possible to write new redirectors (though that requires kernel mode code, there are some development kits that provide the kernel code for you, similar to a Linux FUSE filesystem).

If you want to avoid writing code, WebDAV over HTTPS will provide you secure access (no need for a VPN layer) and software already exists.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how the server on the internet is set up to make its files available. Most often tcpip is not the protocol used for this - it is FTP, SFTP, HTTP or something similar. I believe Windows Explorer uses RPC calls over a local network to accomplish this. I don't think you will be able to use the Open File Dialog, you will have to write something similar that works over the protocol you need to use.

Comment: FTP, SFTP, and HTTP all use TCP connections (just like the question said).